# Changed URL: refused to connect

Tags: site-url

Hope someone can help me, just changed the URL of my site from http://radius7.co.uk to http://kendricks.life and the site and wordpress editor fails to load and just displays "refused to connect". Any pointers? Cheers

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/417736/edit) to explain how you changed the URL.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.